# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame - не пойму как исправить

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, dataframe

Пишу обработчик табличных данных (я начинающий data science:)

Задача простая.

Если значение в столбце «Межпередельный склад» пустое, у строк, где «Подразделение» содержит «смесильно-прессовое» проставить значение «1 Прессование после / Обжиг до»

И так много (~25) условий и циклов.

Я написал таким образом (код ниже) и о чудо, работает, но после 3-го или 4-го обработанного значения выдает

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Код написал следующий:

```
i=0
while i < len(df):
    if df1.sklad[i]== u'Прессование ПОСЛЕ АГРЕГАТОВ':
        value = '1 Прессование после / Обжиг до'
        df1.mezhsklad[i]= value
    i +=1
```

Подскажите, что не так или как оптимизировать, или как написать проще.
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy - посмотрел. Не понятно все равно.

Answer (score 4):

Так как вы уже получили правильный ответ от [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu), я сосредоточию только на эту часть вашего вопроса:

> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy - посмотрел. Не понятно все равно.

---

**Короткий ответ без объяснений:**
*Когда в Pandas влево от `=` находится `][`, вы напрашиваетесь на проблемы.*

В вашем коде `df1.mezhsklad[i] = value`, что тот же самое как

```
            df1['mezhsklad'][i] = value        # здесь индикатор проблем: ][
```

— значит, *могут возникнуть проблемы.*

---

**Длинный ответ с объяснением:**

- Здесь ваша таблица `df1`:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда Pandas видит ваше `df1['mezhsklad'][i] = value`, сделает сначала `df1['mezhsklad']` и результат сохранит во временной переменной:

```
            temp    = df1['mezhsklad']
```

Затем сделает

```
            temp[i] = value
```

Проблема состоит в том — **что находится в переменной `temp`**?

Существуют 2 возможности:

1. `temp` есть столбец `'mezhsklad'` таблицы `df1`:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. `temp` есть **копией** вашего столбца `'mezhsklad'` таблицы `df1`:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит, после присвоения

```
            temp[i] = value
```

- результатом *первой* альтернативы будет *присвоение значения `value` клетке вашей таблицы* (что вы хотите),
- результатом *второй* альтернативы будет изменение *чего-то где-то в памяти* на `value` — значит, **ваша таблица не изменится**.

Pandas не должен знать, какая из этих 2 альтернатив вообще наступит — это зависит от расставленная таблицы в памяти, что нет делом Pandas.

Потому `][` *опасны* — они вынуждают **2 шаги**, а первый из них не полностью определенный.

Потому рекомендуется применить **1-шаговый** `df1.loc[i, 'mezhsklad'] = value`.

Answer (score 3):

Если работая с Pandas вы используете циклы для обработки строк - значит, скорее всего, вы что-то делаете не так.

Аналогия - это как купить спорткар, но пользоваться всегда только первой скоростью.

Используйте векторизированный подход - т.е. рассматривайте все операции как операции с векторами и матрицами, а не с конкретными ячейками матрицы/таблицы:

```
mask = (df['mezhsklad']==0) & (df['sklad']=='Прессование ПОСЛЕ АГРЕГАТОВ')
df1.loc[mask, 'mezhsklad'] = '1 Прессование после / Обжиг до'
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде проблему решил. Необходимо было изменить индексацию

```
i=0
while i < len(df1):
    if df1.loc[i, 'mezhsklad'] == 0:
        if df1.loc[i, 'sklad'] == u'Прессование ПОСЛЕ АГРЕГАТОВ':
            value = '1 Прессование после / Обжиг до'
            df1.loc[i, 'mezhsklad'] = value
```