# Pandas. Действия с частью столбца по условию. trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Returning a view versus a copy

Tags: python, pandas

Датафрейм df_fin:

```
,DATE,DECDATE,HAE_RAW,HAN_RAW,HK2_RAW
0,2019:04:30:00:00,1556539260,7445.47,-5865.28,22330.2
1,2019:04:30:00:01,1556539320,7445.47,-5865.28,22330.2
2,2019:04:30:00:02,1556539380,7445.47,-5865.28,22330.2  
...  
1199518,2021:09:28:23:58,1632830340,-1053620.0,-3168580.0,23419.9
1199519,2021:09:28:23:59,1632830400,-1053490.0,-3168520.0,23418.3
```

Содержит отсчеты снятые с АЦП датчика.
Столбцы:
DATE время отсчета
DECDATE время отсчета в секундах с начала эпохи
HAE_RAW,HAN_RAW,HK2_RAW отсчеты трех параметров снимаемых с датчика.

Чтобы перевести отсчеты в реальные физические значения столбцы параметров домножаются на аппаратурные коэффициенты. В процессе работы датчики менялись, соответственно менялись коэффициенты.
Файл с коэффициентами выглядит так:

```
,start,end,x,y,t
0,2019:04:30:00:00,2021:05:24:23:59,0.0012324169,0.001267882,0.00032246
1,2021:05:25:00:00,2021:06:13:05:25,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,2021:06:13:05:26,2021:09:28:22:36,0.000287286,0.00030345,0.00032246
```

Каждая строка файла содержит начало и конец временного промежутка и коэффициенты применяемые в этот промежуток.
Чтобы домножить значения столбцов df_fin на коэффициенты делал так:

```
coef_df_file = pd.read_csv(conf_fl) #Читаем файл с коэффициентами
for row in coef_df_file.iterrows(): #Последовательно перебираем строки файла
        start, stop, x,y,t = row['start'],row['end'], row['x'],row['y'],row['t'] #Получаем начало, конец в промежутка и три коэффициента
        current_part_of_df_fin = df_fin.loc[df_fin['DATE'].between(start,stop)] #Выбираем нужную часть df_fin в промежутке
        current_part_of_df_fin['HAE'] = current_part_of_df_fin['HAE_RAW'] * x # Домножаем на коэффициенты
        current_part_of_df_fin['HAN'] = current_part_of_df_fin['HAN_RAW'] * y
        current_part_of_df_fin['HK2'] = current_part_of_df_fin['HK2_RAW'] * t
```

Ошибка:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  current_part_of_df_fin['HAE'] = current_part_of_df_fin['HAE_RAW'] * x
```

Почитал предлагаемую ссылку и здесь:[A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame - не пойму как исправить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783732/a-value-is-trying-to-be-set-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-a-dataframe-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba), но понимания как адаптировать к своему случаю не появилось. Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: А нельзя прсто, без цикла сначала доумножить все на все, а потом получить результат с выборкой .between(start, stop)? Избежите тяжелого цикла и ошибок с работой с копией датафрейма.

Comment: Может и можно, но тогда как? Интервалы данных в столбцах выбираются во временных промежутках(т.е. по условию через between). И уже потом к ним применяются соответствующие коэффициенты. Таких промежутков (замен датчиков) хоть и не много (при многолетних наблюдениях бывает до 10 замен), но для перебора интервалов все равно приходится применять цикл. Если есть метод позволяющий делать несколько выборок без цикла буду благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: Ну вот вы просто _сначала_ векторно перемножили столбцы на нужные коэффициенты. А потом сделали выборку, пусть даже в цикле. Смысл в том, что вам не нужно будет через loc перемножать полученные в каждой итерации цикла. просто получили выборку и вывели ее. она уже перемножены была до цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
for index, row in coef_df_file.iterrows(): 
        start, decstart,stop, decstop,x,y,t = row['start'],row['decstart'],row['end'],row['decstop'], row['x'],row['y'],row['t']
        print(start,stop, x,y,t)
        condition = (df_fin['DECDATE'] >= int(decstart)) & (df_fin['DECDATE'] <= int(decstop))
        df_fin.loc[condition, 'HAE'] = df_fin['HAE_RAW'] * x
        df_fin.loc[condition, 'HAN'] = df_fin['HAN_RAW'] * y
        df_fin.loc[condition, 'HK2'] = df_fin['HK2_RAW'] * t
```

Для удобства пришлось в файл коэффициентов ввести дату начала и конца интервала в секундах с начала эпохи (колонки row['decstart'], row['decstop']), хотя можно написать через timestamp, но мне было так удобнее. Здесь не создается лишняя копия датафрейма, при которой появляется ошибка. Работает довольно быстро. Может быть можно написать лучше (без цикла), было бы интересно взглянуть.